# Web Forms Formatting Issue Using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 and I can't seem to get the formatter to unwrap my directive tags. I have this directive tag

```
<%@ Page Title=""
    Language="C#"
    MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Master1.Master"
    EnableEventValidation="false" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="Test" %>
```

and when I format it, nothing happens (keyboard shortcut control+k, control+f). In Visual Studio 2010, it will unwrap the tag so it looks like this.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Master1.Master" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>
```

I've compared settings between the two versions of Visual Studio and I can't see anything different that would affect how directive tags would get unwrapped. What settings do I need to change to get the directive tag to unwrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the the response from the Visual Studio team, this is a known bug and will not be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to my VS2012, the Key combination is the same (Ctrl E, F).

You can look which Combination your VS is using by going in the Edit Menu, then Advanced >.

Comment: They keyboard shortcut is different in my setup because I'm using some custom bindings. I also have a "Selection Format" icon in my toolbar that has the tooltip "Format the currently selected text." This will format markup, but anytime a tag wraps, it doesn't unwrap. I don't have this problem in VS2010.